# What is a text file?

Tags: c, file, character-encoding, text-files, binaryfiles

It is common to differentiate between text files and binary files. But is there a formal definition? I have basically seen two different types of definitions.

The first one states that it is impossible to know if a file is a text file or not just by looking at it's content. You have to consider the intended purpose with the file.

The other definition is more in the style that if all bytes in the file belongs to a certain set of values, then it is a text file. This definition could possibly need some adjustments for more advanced character encodings.

Please enlighten me. What is the definition of a text file? And how does it differ from a binary file?

Comment: There is no universal fit-all definition. Why is it important? The intended purpose one is soometimes appropriate, and the byte range one is sometimes appropriate.

Comment: Besides the aspects listed in the answers, another quality that can have bearing on whether a file is usefully a text file is line length.  A file with 500,000 ordinary printing characters followed by a single newline is arguably a text file, but will probably not be handled properly by most text-file utilities.

Comment: I'd say both "definitions" you've listed are true.  The other thing is that, yes, the second definition "could possibly need some adjustments".  The definition depends both on what your notion of a "printing character" is (ASCII? ISO8859-1? UTF-8?), and which control characters you consider acceptable.  The C Standard text quoted by Jonathan Leffler mentions only horizontal tab and newline, but most people probably wouldn't mind the occasional backspace or form feed or perhaps a few others. (And we could get into crazy existential arguments about whether `\r` is allowed in a text file or not.)

Comment: The SO tag texts for [text-files](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/text-files/info) and [binaryfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/binaryfiles/info) are a good start.  See also Wikipedia [Text file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) and [Binary file ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file).  But no, I don't believe you'll find a single, official definition.

Comment: Besides the Unix vs. Windows (vs. old Mac) conventions on line endings, the other driver for conservative definitions of text files is that once upon a time there were operating systems that supported [*record oriented files*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) which were an explicit part of the filesystem.  Each line of a text file had to fit in a record, with perhaps various other limitations.  Unix was among the operating systems that revolutionized filesystems by declaring that all files were simple, sequential streams of bytes with no other OS-imposed structure.

Comment: In the context of 'C' tag, a text file is one that should be fopen'ed with "t" and binary is one that should be fopen'ed with "b". In most existing environments, any file can be opened with "b", so 'text' is a subset of 'binary'. A short pragmatic definition of 'text' is now: utf-8 without marker. Meaning, try to parse the file as utf-8, if this fails, treat as binary.

Answer (score 4):

On some systems, notably those based on Unix, there is no significant difference between text and binary files.  On other systems, notably systems such as Windows where the line ending is not a newline character, there are important differences.

The C standard defines the differences in [§7.21.2 Streams](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2):

> ¶1 Input and output, whether to or from physical devices such as terminals and tape drives, or whether to or from files supported on structured storage devices, are mapped into logical data streams, whose properties are more uniform than their various inputs and outputs. Two forms of mapping are supported, for text streams and for binary streams.<sup>266)</sup>
>
> ¶2 A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one- to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character. Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character appear when read in is implementation-defined.
>
> ¶3 A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can transparently record internal data. Data read in from a binary stream shall compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream, under the same implementation. Such a stream may, however, have an implementation-defined number of null characters appended to the end of the stream.
>
> <sup>266)</sup> An implementation need not distinguish between text streams and binary streams. In such an implementation, there need be no new-line characters in a text stream nor any limit to the length of a line.

and in [§7.21.3 Files](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3):

> ¶1 A stream is associated with an external file (which may be a physical device) by opening a file, which may involve creating a new file. Creating an existing file causes its former contents to be discarded, if necessary. If a file can support positioning requests (such as a disk file, as opposed to a terminal), then a file position indicator associated with the stream is positioned at the start (character number zero) of the file, unless the file is opened with append mode in which case it is implementation-defined whether the file position indicator is initially positioned at the beginning or the end of the file. The file position indicator is maintained by subsequent reads, writes, and positioning requests, to facilitate an orderly progression through the file.
>
> ¶2 Binary files are not truncated, except as defined in 7.21.5.3. Whether a write on a text stream causes the associated file to be truncated beyond that point is implementation-defined.

Basically, a binary stream is read and written verbatim; there is no interpretation of the contents.  All files on Unix are effectively treated as binary files.  Text files have restrictions on them — no trailing spaces on lines, no control characters other than newline and horizontal tab, last character must be a newline.  What happens if the rules are broken depends on the implementation.

Unquoted paragraphs of the standard deal with wide-character streams and byte streams, and with the orientation of streams and when a stream becomes oriented, etc.

There are rules about seeking in text files that don't apply to binary files.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2017)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) defines it thus:

> ### 3.403 Text File
>
> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed {LINE_MAX} bytes in length, including the <newline> character. Although POSIX.1-2017 does not distinguish between text files and binary files (see the ISO C standard), many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN or INPUT FILES sections.

Tangentially notice also [the *Line* definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206);

> ### 3.206 Line
>
> A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.

... which implies that a non-empty file which does not end with a newline is not proper a text file.

Non-POSIX platforms may well have a different definition, or no proper definition at all.

Comment: This provides a wider context for the C-specific answer by Jonathan Leffler which is probably *per se* closer to what you are actually asking.

Comment: "*... none can exceed {LINE_MAX} bytes in length ...*" very interesting!